# Laravel form request validation

Tags: laravel, validation, php-5.5

Is there any way to get original data in request?
I mean, in my case I want to validate updating user's in the form. I want the email to be unique on emails in database except on the email that user wrote to the form.

Comment: This is perfectly possible using the build in validators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already has a validation rule for this, you can add an id of the user to ignore to your [unique validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique).

```
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($currentUser->id),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this:

```
'email' => ['sometimes', 'email', 'unique:users,email,'.$user->getKey().','.$user->getKeyName().',deleted_at,NULL', 'string'],
```

Not sure if it is the best solution but works. I kind of do not like it because the `$user` is based on hidden input from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it liks this:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$user->id
```

The user id will allow you to keep updating the record but maintain the unique constraint on email. You don't need a hidden input field for $user->id btw.

Comment: I do because form I am updating is binded like so:
`{!! Form::model($customerAddress, ['route' => 'user.update', 'class' => 'form form-horizontal form-user-data']) !!}` and I cannot access `$this->user`  in the request.